# unmet dependencies due to a prevoius PPA repository

Tags: dependencies

On Ubuntu 16.04 I'm trying to install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
```

but I receive the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia : Depends: python3-pyqt5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4) but 5.6+dfsg-1~cura~ppa~201609120727~6~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I think the problem is in the line:

```
but 5.6+dfsg-1~cura~ppa~201609120727~6~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
```

I guess it refers to 'cura' package, that I used in the past to install the 'cura software', via PPA.
In order to eliminate 'cura' I uninstall it, then I deleted from /etc/apt/source.list.d  the line referring to PPA 'cura' repository.

Finally I run

```
apt-get  autoremove
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -f
```

but no luck. The problem persists with exactly the same error; I cannot understand the reference to 'cura' package.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm quite sure in the past I added cura repository with this line: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/cura

Answer (score 0):

try with `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`

Comment: Unfortunately no luck! The problem persists!